# How can i compare dates from user to the ones inside my database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I would like to compare dates a user as added inside a searchbar to the ones inside my database , my goal is to not have 2 dates that are the same for example : if there is already inside of my database  2022/05/26 to 2022/05/30 the user cannot add 2022/05/27 to 2022/05/28.
Any help is welcome

Comment: You could use unique indexes or do you require a "pre-sql" update sort of check?  
 How are the dates stored are they 1 date per row, or a from and to in one row? 
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20automatically%20creates%20a%20unique,mechanism%20that%20enforces%20the%20constraint.

Comment: its one date per row

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Validates Overlap](https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap) ?

Comment: Classic example for the usage of a range data type, including an exclusion constraint: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html